# STORED PROCEDURE

Tags: sql, procedure

Tenho 2 procedures e queria chamar a procedure `sp_is_temporada` na procedure `sp_calcula_curso`, sendo que o valor que a procedure `sp_is_temporada` retornar vai ser usado na procecure `sp_calcula_curso`, e os argumentos que foram passado na procedure `sp_calcula_curso` serão usadas na procedure `sp_is_temporada`.

```
    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS SP_IS_TEMPORADA;
    DELIMITER //
    CREATE PROCEDURE SP_IS_TEMPORADA(IN SPA_CURSO_ID INT, IN SPA_DATA DATE, IN SPA_CURSO_NAVIGATION_ID INT, INOUT SPA_TEMPORADA INT)
BEGIN
    SELECT '1' INTO SPA_TEMPORADA FROM curso_temporada WHERE curso_id = SPA_CURSO_ID and SPA_DATA BETWEEN dt_inicio and dt_fim and IFNULL(curso_navigation_id,1) = IFNULL(SPA_CURSO_NAVIGATION_ID,1);
END //
    DELIMITER ;





   DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS SP_CALCULA_VALOR_CURSO;
   DELIMITER //
   CREATE PROCEDURE SP_CALCULA_VALOR_CURSO (IN SPA_CURSO_ID INT, IN SPA_CURS0_MOEDA_ID INT, IN SPA_IDADE INT, IN SPA_DATA DATE, INOUT SPA_VALOR_CURSO DOUBLE(20,2))
BEGIN        
    SELECT `valor` INTO SPA_VALOR_CURSO FROM curso_preco2 WHERE curso_id = SPA_CURSO_ID AND moeda_id = SPA_CURS0_MOEDA_ID AND SPA_IDADE BETWEEN idade_de  AND idade_ate;        
END//
     DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: E você quer saber como chamar ?

Comment: Eu li algo sobre EXEC, mas eu não consegui entender muito bem, como eu faria pra passar os argumentos da sp_calcula_curso no exec da sp_is_temporada, e como que eu ia retornar isso também..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você tem que definir variáveis.

```
DEFINE @NomeVariavel_1 as INT
DEFINE @NomeVariavel_2 as VARCHAR(100)
DEFINE @NomeVariavel_3 as DATETIME
DEFINE @NomeVariavel_4 as VARCHAR(100)
```

Define quantas variáveis você precisar para que possa passar na *Sproc*.

Depois no `SELECT` que você quer pegar os resultados para passar como parâmetro na outra *Sproc*, você faz:

```
SELECT
    @NomeVariavel_1 = Campo_1,
    @NomeVariavel_2 = Campo_2,
    @NomeVariavel_3 = Campo_3,
    @NomeVariavel_4 = Campo_4,
FROM
    Tabela
```

Feito isso você pode chamar a *Sproc* pelo comando `exec` colocando como parâmetros as variáveis.

```
EXEC SP_NOME_STORED_PROCEDURE @NomeVariavel_1, @NomeVariavel_2, @NomeVariavel_3, @NomeVariavel_4
```

### Agora

Por que você precisa de duas *Sproc* ?

Não tem como fazer o que você quer em uma só ?

Com variáveis isto é possível.

Analise bem e nos retorne para qualquer dúvida.